# Feed from Analog Camera

Tags: opencv, video-capture

Can I take the image feed from Analog Camera using OpenCV, in a similar manner as it is done using the Digital Camera?

As-In the concept of FPS, does that work similarly with the Analog Camera's?

Thank You.

Comment: i struggled with the same problem and hope it helps!

[the original thread + answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146205/grab-frame-ntsctousb-dongle-opencv2-python-wrapper/22183737#22183737)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I used in the past is a Video to USB Converter. I used [this one](http://www.conrad-international.com/AV-USB-2.0-Converter-with-special-software.htm?websale7=conrad-int&pi=751797&ci=SHOP_AREA_17188_0804290). I used it on Windows, but it might support also other platforms.

I didn't try it, but the camera interface should work directly with the OpenCV capture functionality.

Analog cameras have a fixed FPS. If I am not mistaken it is different for PAL and NTSC, try searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically connect a CCTV camera to a capture board and then process as normal.  Example cards can be found on the ZoneMinder site, software for video surveillance.

http://www.zoneminder.com/shop.html