# Acquiring images from avertv hybrid volar hd in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, live-streaming, data-acquisition

I want to acquire images from a live video that is getting streamed through avertv hybrid volarhd device (A TV to PC adapter).
The device is being identified as a "Video Controller" instead of an "Imaging device" in the device manager(This seems to be the problem when I checked other similar questions online).
So far I have tried using the Image Acquisition Toolbox of MATLAB, but I am unable to acquire any frames.
I have also tried using OpenCV with Python but the VideoCapture function is unable to recognise my device. Please tell me an alternative module/library/ method to do so in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183737/4775626

The method suggested in this answer works for me. The DVdriver software works for me with few tweaks in the settings. Thanks to the original poster for a workaround.